# How browser's "suggestion list" works?

Tags: browser, autosuggest

Many websites use `<input type='text'>` element to get simple text data from their customers. You can configure your browser to remember the values you enter into these fields, so that it can suggest you back a list of values, to speed up your data entry experience.

However, I'm seeing a strange behavior. On some fields of the same type, browser doesn't suggest anything, or suggests a different list from other fields. I've checked all fields and all of them are of the same `<input type='text'>` type.

Does anybody know how browser differentiates between different lists (or no list) for the same HTML form control?

Answer (score 1):

There's an attribute on form elements that allows them to semantically specify their intended content (I believe its the V_Card attribute).

The following page gives a brief explanation and a table of acceptable values:
http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-input-formats